# Trouble with audio composition using Twilio

Tags: audio, twilio

I'm using Twilio video and audio recording using  group rooms.
I have troubles with frames lost with audio files.
The frame lost in audio files occurs in 40% aprox., it is a lost from 1 second to various seconds, many times in different parts of the audio file.
Because I compose both audio (Caller A and Caller B) and I get a not synchronized audio (in some place).

We can not use Twilio Composition API, because we have to (download and) delete the media files after each recording.

How I can improve this? Other users of Twilio have this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you are not using the composition API, how are you composing the files? When you download the files is the audio complete? Is it only after you are composing the audio files yourself that you lose audio?

Comment: I am composing using ffmpeg (recommended by Twilio), for instance:
ffmpeg -i rec3/RT91ddb2....mka -i rec3/RT3d86a5a1.....mka -filter_complex "[1]adelay=47544|47544[d];[0][d]amix=inputs=2" -c:a aac -strict -2 output_audio.mp4

[ When you download ... complete?]
And yes, we download when I see that the recording is complete (using Twilio api)

[ Is it only after you are composing ....]
No, I made a testing environment using wavesurfer.js with 2 players and I can see that the original file (before composing) have the frame lost issue, because I can detect it when playing.

Comment: If you are not getting the full audio from Twilio then this isn’t something that Stack Overflow can help with and you should contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: Thanks philnash, I tried here, to see if someone had the same issue (and may be a way work around with it)

Comment: If you are downloading a file and it has broken audio, I don’t think there’s a workaround for it (unless something is wrong with how you are downloading the file, but you didn’t share that). If there’s just broken audio, then you need to check with support to see what’s up with your account. I guess the other thing to check is if that’s for all audio or whether the issue was with the connection to the participants and that the dropped audio was dropped due to their connection. But support can look into that if you have a room SID they can check.